# What is the difference between "marker.setVisible(false)" and "marker.setMap(null)" in Google Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to clear a marker on Google Maps.

What is the difference between `marker.setVisible(false)` and `marker.setMap(null)`?

But I don't know, which is right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The difference between the two methods does not seem to be clearly documented. However, note the following:

- When you use `setMap(null)`, your marker will lose the reference to the `Map`. If you do not keep a reference to the `Map` object, you wouldn't be able to reshow the marker.
- In addition, the `setMap()` method will not trigger the `visible_changed` event, while the `setVisible()` method does (if the visibility is actually toggled).

Example:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363, 131.044), 
  map: map
}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'visible_changed', function() {
  console.log('visible_changed triggered');
});

marker.setVisible(false); // visible_changed triggered
marker.setVisible(true);  // visible_changed triggered
marker.setMap(null);      // visible_changed not triggered
marker.setMap(map);       // visible_changed not triggered
```

I guess we should be using the `setVisible(false)` method when we intend to reshow the marker again on the map, and the `setMap(null)` when we will not be showing it again.

Answer (score 12):

Another key distinction is that `setMap(NULL)` releases the resources associated with the marker whereas `setVisible(false)` just makes the marker invisible, but the resources associated with the marker are still allocated.

If you're dealing with 100s or 1000s of markers, this can become a significant performance and memory issue.

Comment: In summary, `setMap(null)` would yield better performance for 1000s of markers