# Hide and show for custom markers not working in my google map

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a custom Google map with markers of artist locations. I want to make 8 different categories of markers. I read about having to make arrays of markers and assigning a category, but I honestly don't know where to start..

I think this question comes close to what I want: [Toggle on/off Google map markers by category](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827964). Tried to get that working, but to no avail, I just have too little knowledge.

I have a map and two checkboxes ready, the checkboxes aren't used yet.
I'm new to google maps So.. What's the best way to create different arrays of markers and toggle their visibility with check boxes? 
Please help me
Thanks

```
    var marker;
    var infowindow;
var map;
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};
 var markerGroups = { "restaurant": [], "bar": []};
//alert(markerGroups);
function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.9200, 75.8200);
  var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
  var html = "<table>" +
             "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
             "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
             "<option value='bar' SELECTED>bar</option>" +
             "<option value='restaurant'>restaurant</option>" +
             "</select> </td></tr>" +
             "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: html
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map,
     draggable: true
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
/*******************Start code for fetch record****************/ 
downloadUrl("include/phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    //alert(xml);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      //alert(icon);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      markerGroups[type].push(marker);
      var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type);
    marker.setMap(map);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }

  });
  /*******************End code for fetch record****************/ 
}
/*******************Start code for show detail****************/ 

 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
 /*******************End code for show record****************/ 
function saveData() {
  var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
  var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
  var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
  var latlng = marker.getPosition();

  var url = "include/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
            "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
            //alert(url);
  downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
    if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
      infowindow.close();
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
    }
  });
}
function createMarker(point, name, address, type) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(point, customIcons[type]);
return marker;
}
   function toggleGroup(type) {
    //alert(type);
for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
    //alert(markerGroups);
var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
    //alert(marker);
    if (marker.getMap() === null) {
    marker.setMap(map);
    //alert(map);
        } else {
    marker.setMap(null);
            }
         }
         }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);//right here
      //callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Here's my html

```
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onLoad="initialize();">
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="sidebar" style="float:left; width: 120px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black">
<input id="restaurantCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked="" onClick="toggleGroup('restaurant')">
Restaurants
<br>
<input id="barCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked="" onClick="toggleGroup('bar')">
Bars
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setVisible(false)` instead of `setMap(null)`.
As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647711/what-is-the-difference-between-marker-setvisiblefalse-and-marker-setmapnul) `setMap()` will not refresh the drawing of the map and hence you will not see anything change. `setMap()` seems also to be the wrong choice if you want to reshow the marker later.

Edit: To summarize the comments: When using `setVisible()` you will have to check for the value of `marker.getVisible()` instead of `marker.getMap()`.

Comment: I have also try setvisible() true or false but not work. Thanks

Comment: @Chetan hada Could you be more specific about what the error is? Does the map get displayed at all (and the markers)?

Comment: No Error show in firebug.The problem is when i unchecked the check box now markers are hide but problem is when i checked again check box  marker's not show. Thanks

Comment: @Chetan hada So your code was `if (marker.getVisible() === false) {
    marker.setVisible(true);
    //alert(map);
        } else {
    marker.setVisible(false);
            }` and did only hide markers but did not reshow them properly?